# .NET Windows Forms custom control, how to create the quick menu

Tags: .net, winforms, custom-controls, contextmenu

Some controls have a useful context menu to access some often used properties, for example the standard TextBox:

[image: TextBox showing a little arrow]

Clicking the arrow you get:

[image: Clicking on the arrow a context menu appears]

How do I accomplish that with a custom control? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should create your own control designer which can provide verbs as custom menu items or UI enhancements to the VS form designer.

> Designer:
>
> A class that takes care of the appearance and behavior of the control
>   when hosted in Visual Studio .NET. You can use this class to add new
>   context menu verbs and, for ASP.NET controls, to explicitly indicate
>   the HTML code to show in the designer.

check here for the full article:

[Custom Design-time Control Features in Visual Studio .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164048.aspx#S6)

Comment: Is it possible to use it in run-time?